# copy selected dependencies with maven assembly plugin along with their transitive dependencies

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I want to copy selected dependencies(use include filter) with maven assembly plugin along with their transitive dependencies. For example (snippet from assembly descriptor):

```
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
            <useTransitiveDependencies>true</useTransitiveDependencies>
            <unpack>false</unpack>
            <includes>
                <include>gpid:artifcatid</include>

            </includes>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
```

This is just copying a single jar to the destination directory. I expected it to copy all the transitive dependencies as well with this. 
How can this be achieved ?
I hope we are not supposed to list down all the jars individually.

Comment: I guess that this plugin first creates the list of all transitive dependencies and then filters for the include.

Comment: @JFMeier so is there any way in maven this can be achieved ?

Comment: Actually, this is not really well defined. Transitive dependency resolution comes with dependency mediation. If Maven finds several versions of e.g. log4j in your dependency tree, it has various means to choose one. If you want to do dependency resolution for a subset of your dependencies, you need to say how dependency meditation should work. Should it act as if your not included dependencies were not there at all (i.e. maybe choosing a different log4j than before), should it mix both sources of information, or what else?